# Ocultar parte de um texto com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma tabela que é preenchida com dados vindos de um banco.
Uma das colunas contém um texto que em algumas vezes é longo ( mais de 1000 caracteres). Quero limitar a visualização deste texto na tabela em 300 caracteres e adicionar um botão do tipo "leia mais" se o usuário quiser exibir o restante.

Sei que tem como fazer isso adicionando uma marcação no texto com HTML e a função `toggle` do jQuery, mas como o texto vem do banco, não tenho como inserir esta marcação.

Existe alguma outra forma?

Comment: Como você popula os dados na tela?

Comment: Retorno os dados da consulta ao banco, imprimindo com PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tire proveito dos atributos data para lhe facilitar a vida, neste caso no botão para mostrar mais `data-mais` vai ter o texto completo e no botão para mostrar menos `data-menos` vai ter o texto limitado, consoante em qual deles clica o texto correspondente vai ser 'injetado' da `td` com a classe `hide-text` pertencente à mesma linha. Veja se se adequa ao seu problema

```js
$('.mais').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.hide-text').html($(this).data('mais'));
});
$('.menos').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.hide-text').html($(this).data('menos'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td class="hide-text">STO</td>
  <td><button data-mais="ISTO é o texto completo1" class="mais">Mostrar mais</button>
<button data-menos="STO" class="menos">Mostrar menos</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td class="hide-text">STO</td>
  <td><button data-mais="ISTO é o texto completo2" class="mais">Mostrar mais</button>
<button data-menos="STO" class="menos">Mostrar menos</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td class="hide-text">STO</td>
  <td><button data-mais="ISTO é o texto completo3" class="mais">Mostrar mais</button>
<button data-menos="STO" class="menos">Mostrar menos</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
```

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/hghLee3x/) no jsfiddle